# Get text from HTML tags using JavaSscript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get text from anchor tag shoved below.
Currently I have:

```
<a href="#">
  "Text I want to get"
  <div class="dropdown-icon"><img src="" alt="#">
  </div>
</a>
```

So I want to get only text from anchor tag ("Text I want to get"), wihout all other stuff. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.innerText`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('a').innerText)
```

```html
<a href="#">
  "Text I want to get"
  <div class="dropdown-icon"><img src="" alt="#">
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

```
let anchorTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
console.log(anchorTag.innerText);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use innertext and also you can use textContent properties and for that visit MDN web Docs.

```
use = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
file = use.innerText
```